# TFS MSBuild copy command

Tags: tfs, msbuild

The is my copy command:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <SwfFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin-release\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<CallTarget Targets="CopyFilesToDropLocation"/>

<Target Name="CopyFilesToDropLocation">

<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(SwfFiles)"
    DestinationFiles="@(SwfFiles->'$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\PrismWeb\%         (RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>

</Target>
```

I dont anything being copied to the destinaton. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put a Message Task to see what your values are, then you can adjust it, and with no error message it is hard to help you out

Comment: What version of TFS is this?

Answer (score 0):

IS this space for hiding values ?

DestinationFiles="@(SwfFiles->'$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\PrismWeb\%  [here]       (RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>

I tested this with some of my code

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceAllFiles)" DestinationFiles="%              (RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)'" />
```

This space will produce a copy that works, but it tries to copy the source to this destination:

```
% [nbSpaces](RecursiveDir)[this part of the metadata woks]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest build template in TFS 2013.4. It has defined locations for executing PowerShell, one of which is post-build. Using Powershell is both easyer to debug and more future proof.